# Conditional mutating with dplyr for only some rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I use `ifelse` with `mutate` to conditionally change variable names within a column. For example:

```
mutate(df, thiscol = ifelse((new == "oldname"), "newname", NA)
```

But I would like to change it so that instead of variables that don't fit the conditions turning into NA, they just stay as they were.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mutate(df, thiscol = ifelse(new == "oldname", "newname", thiscol))`

Comment: this parenthesis `"oldname"),"newname"` should be at the end of `thiscol)`?

Answer (score 2):

If we need to change only some elements and keep the rest as the same, then another option is `replace`

```
df %>%
    mutate(thiscol = replace(thiscol, new == "oldname", "newname"))
```